# Getting "Access Violation" error while resize PDF using GhostScript

Tags: python, ghostscript, pypdf

I am trying to resize PDF using GhostScipt. But getting error [image: with this code.]

Below is the code for the function pdfresize.
**pdffile** is the file path to the input file.
**ann** is the name of the file
**intFiles2** is the global variable of the folder path.

I also doing pdf to jpg using ghostscript on the paths specified above and it worked perfectly.

```
def pdfResizeGS(pdffile,ann):
    command = "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=612 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=1008 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -o "+intFiles+"/"+ann+".pdf"+" "+pdffile
    args =[
        "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite",
        "-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=612",
        "-dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=1008",
        "-dFIXEDMEDIA",
        "-dPDFFitPage",
        "-dCompatibilityLevel=1.5",
        "-o "+intFiles2+"/"+ann+".pdf",
        pdffile
        ]
    
    encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()
    args = [a.encode(encoding) for a in args]
    print (args)
    with ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args) as g:
        ghostscript.cleanup()
    
    return 1
```

Comment: Don't know what `intfFiles2` is.  Do you have appropriate permissions to write there?

Comment: intfiles is a glboal varaible of path. 
Yes i do have appropriate permissions. It worked with JPG files

Comment: Also, I am creating a new folder using same python script. and the same folder path is being passed in intFiles2